# How to use alpha map textures with ShaderMaterial in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl, textures, shader

I have a png image (16x16) that I want to use as an alpha map texture, in a custom material `THREE.ShaderMaterial`. This is the image:

[image: Alpha Map]

This is the setup for my preloaded Texture object:

```
alphaMap.magFilter = THREE.NearestFilter
alphaMap.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping
alphaMap.repeat.y = 10
alphaMap.needsUpdate = true
```

In the properties of the ShaderMaterial I added:

```
transparent: true
```

Then added `defines`:

```
USE_ALPHAMAP: true,
ALPHATEST: 0.5
```

And finally the `uniform`:

```
alphaMap: { type: 't', value: alphaMap }
```

I don't get any errors but the mesh is not visible. If i set it as `diffuseColor.rgb` the mesh is all black. What is missing or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this problem (not documented) was:

```
uniforms['alphaMap'].value.needsUpdate = true
```

Doing this won't work:

```
alphaMap.needsUpdate = true
```

It should probably be added here: [How to update things](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/How-to-update-things) (the need of `needsUpdate` flag for textures is actually there, but it's not clear how to deal with ShaderMaterial and uniforms).